# Calculate sum of the digits to the consecutive power in given number

Tags: java, algorithm

What is the best way to calculate sum of the digits to the consecutive power in a method?

Examples:

```
calculateSum(5) -> returns 5^1 = 5
12 -> 1^1 + 2^2 = 5
26 -> 2^1 + 6^2 = 38
122 -> 1^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 13
```

I wanted to use stream because I'm trying to practice some J8 functionalities but couldn't find a way to make it work.

EDIT: I need it to solve this kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5626b561280a42ecc50000d1/train/java

EDIT2: Here is my code so far:

```
public static void calculateSum(int input) {
    String[] number = String.valueOf(input).split("");
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(number)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .map(d -> (int) Math.pow(d, list.indexOf(d)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(d));
}
```

I don't know how to map digits from `number array` with their consecutive powers so then I can just sum values from that map.

Comment: Show something you have tried, then we can work from there

Comment: For negative integers?

Comment: Consider [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce) or (considering that the word "collect" appears in the kata) [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#collect).

Can you feed a `long` to `reduce`/`collect`? If not, what can you do instead?

Comment: @smac89 Added edit.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz just positives.

Comment: @doublemc `Math.pow(d, list.indexOf(d))` gives incorrect power for repeating digits.

Comment: I know, my code isn't working.

Comment: if you want to solve using streams, you should stream the index range, e.g. `IntStream.range(0, myarray.length)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution without streams.

```
public static int digitPow(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    int count = (int)(Math.log10(n) + 1); // number of digits in n

    while (count > 0) {
        result += Math.pow((n % 10), count);
        n /= 10;
        count--;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how the hell you came up with this int count using Math.log10? It's brilliant, what was your though process?

Comment: @doublemc log10 is the standard way of calculating the number of digits base 10.

Comment: @doublemc Log base `b` of `x`, where `x` is a number in base `b`, tells you the number of times you can divide `x` by `b` before it goes to less than `b`. Note that since `x` is a number in base `b`, each time you divide `x` by `b`, you eliminate one digit from it. Using that knowledge, you can now say that the number of digits in a base 10 number is the log base 10 of that number, plus 1. The plus one comes from the fact that log only goes until the number is less than the base, so we include the last digit to give the full count.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for You:

```

```
String str = String.valueOf(122);
DoubleSummaryStatistics collect = IntStream.range(0, str.length()) //1
    .mapToObj(i -> {
        int digit = Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 10); //2
        return Math.pow(digit, i + 1); //3
    })
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(i -> i)); //4

System.out.println(collect.getSum());
```

```

1. generate power values
2. extract digit from char at given position
3. calculate power of extracted number
4. summarize everything

Comment: Ive used streams as You asked :)

Answer (score 2):

To fix what you already had, the trick is to use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

```
public static void calculateSum(int input) {
    String[] number = String.valueOf(input).split("");
    int sum = IntStream.range(0, number.length)
        .map(i -> (int)Math.pow(Integer.valueOf(number[i]), i + 1))
        .sum();

    System.out.println(sum)
}
```

Comment: Is much less complicated than my version :) i see simple code, i upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

*FYI:* Stream is not a good solution to this kind of problem. Forcing the use of Streams is bad coding. Part of writing good code, is to recognize the correct tool for the job, and Stream is not the tool to use here.

To prevent any potential issues with inaccuracy of `double`, here is a pure-`int` solution:

```
private static int calculateSum(int input) {
    if (input < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative: " + input);
    int[] digit = new int[10], power = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0, n = input; n != 0; i++, n /= 10) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            power[j] *= digit[j];
        power[i] = digit[i] = n % 10;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        sum += power[i];
    if (sum < 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Overflow: " + input);
    return sum;
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(5);
    test(12);
    test(26);
    test(122);
    test(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    test(1999999998);
}
private static void test(int input) {
    System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", input, calculateSum(input));
}
```

*Output*

```
5 -> 5
12 -> 5
26 -> 38
122 -> 13
2147483647 -> 284684832
1999999998 -> 1509589865
```

Note that a 10-digit number ending in `9` will overflow.

Comment: Well, looking at some of the answers, streams seem to be very powerful (short and concise) and can be used almost everywhere where we need to work with arrays, comparisons and such.